# How to send xml string from rest web service to jsp

Tags: xml, rest, jsp, jersey

I POST xml data from index.html to rest web service(jersey) and now I want to send the another xml file to a jsp file. So how I can send xml from rest web service to jsp as we can do in servlet by using set/get attributes?

Comment: _"send xml from rest web service to jsp"_ - This doesn't make much sense to me. Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: @Path("/listOperations")
public class listOperations extends HttpServlet {
 String result="abc";
 @POST
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
 public void getOperation(String input){some operations.......................}}Now i have to send a response from this class to a jsp page but not the one from which it have got "input" string

Comment: Actually we use return statement to send response but it sends the respone from where it have got the request but here I want to send response to any other jsp page